# Footer Page Numbering Not Displayed in TOC

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a Microsoft WORD 2010 document that has different sections with dual page numbering. Thus, I can have a page numbering system in the Header of each section in the format X of Y.

For example in Section 1, I have 10 pages, so the first page in that section has **1** of **10** pages in the Header. I formatted the numbering in the **Header** of each section, so this part of it is fine.

Now I have regular page numbering for each page in the document in the **Footer** of each page (for example Page 1, Page 2, Page 3 etc.).

My issue is that when I insert an automatic table of contents, it inserts the page number from the Header of each section. So for each section in the table of contents, the page number restarts at Page 1. How do I get the automatic table of contents to display the page numbering from the Footer of each section instead so that it can show consecutive numbering? No one seems to be able to figure this issue out.

Comment: can you please press ALT+F9 and let us know the field code of the field in the header as well as the footer?